# Cobol xml parse got exception

Tags: xml, exception, cobol, zos

### Cobol xml parse throws exception +000528897

Reading xml from a file or even xml declared in "working storage" as a string array

### The Cobol parse command:

`XML PARSE XML-STRING PROCEDURE XML-HANDLER`

throws exception +000528897

I checked if the xml is well formed (displayed in browser) and it's ok

[image]

I displayed the xml string after reading it from a file and concatenating all the lines as a long string

[image]

We are using Cobol 5.2

compiler option -> xmlparse(xmlss)

If I change the option to xmlparse(compat) the exception is 72

### This is the Cobol source

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. TDXMLTST.
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
  *************************
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT  XMLDATA       ASSIGN TO XMLFILE.
 DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
  *=================================================================
   FD  XMLDATA
       RECORDING MODE IS F
       LABEL RECORD STANDARD
       DATA RECORD IS XMLREC.
   01  XMLREC   PIC X(80).
 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
  ******************************************************************
  * XML DOCUMENT, ENCODED AS INITIAL VALUES OF DATA ITEMS.         *
  ******************************************************************
   01 NOT-EOF                   PIC X(01)      VALUE 'N'.
   01 I-FROM                    PIC S9(4)   COMP VALUE 0.
   01 XML-STRING                PIC X(1000) VALUE SPACES.
   01 EZ-PTR                    PIC S9(4) COMP VALUE 1.
  ******************************************************************

  ******************************************************************
  * SAMPLE DATA DEFINITIONS FOR PROCESSING NUMERIC XML CONTENT.    *
  ******************************************************************

     1 CURRENT-ELEMENT PIC X(30).
     1 LIST-PRICE COMPUTATIONAL PIC 9V99 VALUE 0.
     1 DISCOUNT COMPUTATIONAL PIC 9V99 VALUE 0.
     1 DISPLAY-PRICE PIC $$9.99.
   
 PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    MAINLINE SECTION.
       PERFORM READ-XML-FILE
       DISPLAY 'XML-DOCUMENT=' XML-STRING(1:EZ-PTR)
       XML PARSE XML-STRING(1:EZ-PTR)
                          PROCESSING PROCEDURE XML-HANDLER
         ON EXCEPTION
           DISPLAY 'XML DOCUMENT ERROR ' XML-CODE
         NOT ON EXCEPTION
           DISPLAY 'XML DOCUMENT SUCCESSFULLY PARSED'
       END-XML

  ******************************************************************
  *    PROCESS THE TRANSFORMED CONTENT AND CALCULATE PROMO PRICE.  *
  ******************************************************************

       DISPLAY ' '
       DISPLAY '-----+++++***** USING INFORMATION FROM XML '
           '*****+++++-----'
       DISPLAY ' '
       MOVE LIST-PRICE TO DISPLAY-PRICE
       DISPLAY '  SANDWICH LIST PRICE: ' DISPLAY-PRICE
       COMPUTE DISPLAY-PRICE = LIST-PRICE * (1 - DISCOUNT)
       DISPLAY '  PROMOTIONAL PRICE:   ' DISPLAY-PRICE
       DISPLAY '  GET ONE TODAY!'
       GOBACK.

    MAINLINE-EXIT. EXIT.

  READ-XML-FILE  SECTION.

       OPEN INPUT XMLDATA
       PERFORM UNTIL NOT-EOF = 'Y'
            READ XMLDATA
              AT END MOVE 'Y' TO NOT-EOF
            END-READ
            IF NOT-EOF = 'N' THEN
              PERFORM VARYING I-FROM
                     FROM 72
                       BY -1
                    UNTIL XMLREC(I-FROM:1) NOT = ' '
              END-PERFORM

              STRING XMLREC(1:I-FROM) DELIMITED BY SIZE
                INTO XML-STRING
                WITH POINTER EZ-PTR
              END-STRING

              DISPLAY 'EZ-PTR=' EZ-PTR
            END-IF
       END-PERFORM
       CLOSE XMLDATA
       .

   READ-XML-FILE-EXIT. EXIT.

   XML-HANDLER SECTION.
       DISPLAY 'XML-EVENT=' XML-EVENT
       EVALUATE XML-EVENT

  * ==> ORDER XML EVENTS MOST FREQUENT FIRST
         WHEN 'START-OF-ELEMENT'
           DISPLAY 'START ELEMENT TAG: <' XML-TEXT '>'
           MOVE XML-TEXT TO CURRENT-ELEMENT
         WHEN 'CONTENT-CHARACTERS'
           DISPLAY 'CONTENT CHARACTERS: <' XML-TEXT '>'

  * ==> TRANSFORM XML CONTENT TO OPERATIONAL COBOL DATA ITEM...
           EVALUATE CURRENT-ELEMENT
             WHEN 'LISTPRICE'

  * ==> USING FUNCTION NUMVAL-C...
               COMPUTE LIST-PRICE = FUNCTION NUMVAL-C(XML-TEXT)
             WHEN 'DISCOUNT'
               COMPUTE DISCOUNT = FUNCTION NUMVAL-C(XML-TEXT)
           END-EVALUATE
         WHEN 'END-OF-ELEMENT'
           DISPLAY 'END ELEMENT TAG: <' XML-TEXT '>'
           MOVE SPACES TO CURRENT-ELEMENT
         WHEN 'START-OF-DOCUMENT'
           COMPUTE XML-DOCUMENT-LENGTH = FUNCTION LENGTH(XML-TEXT)
           DISPLAY 'START OF DOCUMENT: LENGTH=' XML-DOCUMENT-LENGTH
               ' CHARACTERS.'
         WHEN 'END-OF-DOCUMENT'
           DISPLAY 'END OF DOCUMENT.'
         WHEN 'VERSION-INFORMATION'
           DISPLAY 'VERSION: <' XML-TEXT '>'
         WHEN 'ENCODING-DECLARATION'
           DISPLAY 'ENCODING: <' XML-TEXT '>'
         WHEN 'STANDALONE-DECLARATION'
           DISPLAY 'STANDALONE: <' XML-TEXT '>'
         WHEN 'ATTRIBUTE-NAME'
           DISPLAY 'ATTRIBUTE NAME: <' XML-TEXT '>'
         WHEN 'ATTRIBUTE-CHARACTERS'
           DISPLAY 'ATTRIBUTE VALUE CHARACTERS: <' XML-TEXT '>'
         WHEN 'ATTRIBUTE-CHARACTER'
           DISPLAY 'ATTRIBUTE VALUE CHARACTER: <' XML-TEXT '>'
         WHEN 'START-OF-CDATA-SECTION'
           DISPLAY 'START OF CDATA: <' XML-TEXT '>'
         WHEN 'END-OF-CDATA-SECTION'
           DISPLAY 'END OF CDATA: <' XML-TEXT '>'
         WHEN 'CONTENT-CHARACTER'
           DISPLAY 'CONTENT CHARACTER: <' XML-TEXT '>'
         WHEN 'PROCESSING-INSTRUCTION-TARGET'
           DISPLAY 'PI TARGET: <' XML-TEXT '>'
         WHEN 'PROCESSING-INSTRUCTION-DATA'
           DISPLAY 'PI DATA: <' XML-TEXT '>'
         WHEN 'COMMENT'
           DISPLAY 'COMMENT: <' XML-TEXT '>'
         WHEN 'EXCEPTION'
  *         COMPUTE XML-DOCUMENT-LENGTH = FUNCTION LENGTH (XML-TEXT)
           DISPLAY 'EXCEPTION ' XML-CODE ' AT OFFSET '
               EZ-PTR '.'
           MOVE -1 TO XML-CODE
           MOVE 16 TO RETURN-CODE
         WHEN OTHER
           DISPLAY 'UNEXPECTED XML EVENT: ' XML-EVENT '.'
       END-EVALUATE
       .

   XML-HANDLER-EXIT. EXIT.
```

XML DOCUMENT ERROR +000528897

Comment: The text in your string has 52 characters but the EZ-PTR contains the value 53.  Is there odd text past the end of your XML string that is causing a parse error?

Comment: i think that it is not matter because over the last xml tag there have spaces . i subtract  1 from the variable and the result was asis

Answer (score 5):

You have a CCSID problem, which can be solved by either...

- adding `CODEPAGE(1140)` to your compile options via whichever method is accepted in your shop
- adding the `ENCODING 1140` phrase to your XML PARSE statement

When using the XMLPARSE(COMPAT) compile option (the "native COBOL" parser), the XML-CODE value of 72 is [documented](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=effect-xml-parse-exceptions-that-allow-continuation) as...

> The actual document encoding was EBCDIC, the CODEPAGE compiler option
> did not specify a supported EBCDIC code page, and the document did not
> contain an encoding declaration.

When using the XMLPARSE(XMLSS) compile option (the z/OS XML System Services parser), the XML-CODE value is the [concatenation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=material-xml-parse-exceptions-xmlparsexmlss-in-effect) of XML Return Code and XML Reason Code, each is a halfword.  Decimal +000528897 is x'81201' so the XML Reason Code is 1201 and the XML Return Code is 8.  Return code 8 is [documented](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=reference-return-codes-listed-by-value) as "XRC_FAILURE" with the note...

> Processing failed. Returned data areas and parms valid.

...and reason code 1201 is [documented](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=reference-reason-codes-listed-by-value) as...

> XRSN_PARM_ENCODING_SPEC_INVALID The ccsid passed is not supported.
> Action: The CCSID parameter on the call to GXL1INI or GXL4INI is not
> one of the supported character encodings. Pass only permitted CCSID
> parameters. See the documentation of the GXL1INI service for supported
> ccsid constants.